# How do I print 11 22 33 41 52 63 in php?

Tags: php

I have written this code from this code I want to print just 11 22 33 41 52 63
How to do that ?

```
<?php
   for($i=1;$i<=6;$i++){
       for($j=1;$j<=3;$j++){
           echo $i.$j."\n";
       }
   }
?>
```

Comment: `echo "11 22 33 41 52 63"`

Comment: @DanielKrom lol. :D What a nice answer.

Comment: i think you miss ** ; ** @DanielKrom

Comment: @DanielKrom +1 for simplicity! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for an algorithm:

```
<?php
$n=1;
for ($i=1;$i<=2;$i++){
    for($j=1;$j<=3;$j++){
        echo $n.$j."\n";
        $n++;
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this program

```
<?php
   for($i=1;$i<=6;$i++){
       for($j=1;$j<=6;$j++){
           if($i <= 3)
            $k1=$i;
            else{
            $k1=$i-3;   
            }

       }
       //print in newline
       echo $i.$k1."<br>";
       //print in same line
       //echo $i.$k1." ";

   }
?>
```